# Feedback + Bad output

Tags: c++, class, header, output

So I've got an assignment I think I'm more or less done with, but there is something which is messing up the output badly somewhere down the line, or even the calculation, and I don't see where the problem is.

The assignment is to make a game in which a certain ammount of players run up through a tunnel towards a spot,where they will stop and spin around it,and then their dizziness is supposed to make them randomly either progress towards goal or regress back towards start.And each time they get another spot closer to goal,they get another "marking",and it goes on like this until one of them reaches goal.

The program includes three files: one main.cpp,one header file and another cpp file.

The header file:

```
    #ifndef COMPETITOR_H
    #define COMPETITOR_H

    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class Competitor
    {
        public:
            void setName();
            string getName();
            void spin();
            void move();
            int checkScore();
            void printResult();

        private:
            string name;
            int direction;
            int markedSpots;
    };

    #endif // COMPETITOR_H
```

The second cpp file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include "Competitor.h"


    using namespace std;



    void Competitor::setName()
    {
        cin>>name;
    }

    string Competitor::getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    void Competitor::spin()        
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        direction = rand()%1+0;
    }

    void Competitor::move()         
    {                               
        if(direction == 1)
        {
            markedSpots++;
        }
        else if(direction == 0 && markedSpots != 0)
        {
            markedSpots--;
        }
    }

    int Competitor::checkScore()
    {
        return markedSpots;
    }

    void Competitor::printResult() 
    {
        if(direction == 1)
        {
            cout<<" is heading towards goal and has currently "<<markedSpots<<" markings.";
        }
        else if(direction == 0)
        {
            cout<<"\n"<<getName()<<" is heading towards start and has currently "<<markedSpots<<" markings.";
        }
    }
```

The main cpp file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include "Competitor.h"

    using namespace std;

    void inputAndSetNames(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps);
    void makeTwist(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps);
    void makeMove(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps);
    void showAll(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps);
    int winner(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps, int nrOfTwistPlaces);

    int main()
    {

        int nrOfTwistPlaces;
        int nrOfComps;
        int noWinner = -1;
        int laps = 0;

        cout<<"How many spinning places should there be? ";
        cin>>nrOfTwistPlaces;
        cout<<"How many competitors should there be? ";
        cin>>nrOfComps;

        Competitor * comps = new Competitor[nrOfComps];

        inputAndSetNames(comps, nrOfComps);

        do
        {
            laps++;

            cout<<"\nSpin "<<laps<<":";
            makeTwist(comps, nrOfComps);
            makeMove(comps, nrOfComps);
            showAll(comps, nrOfComps);

        }while(noWinner == -1);

        delete [] comps;

        return 0;
    }


    void inputAndSetNames(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps)
    {
        cout<<"Type in the names of the "<<nrOfComps<<" competitors:\n";
        for(int i=0;i<nrOfComps;i++)
        {
            comps[i].setName();
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    void makeTwist(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<nrOfComps;i++)
        {
            comps[i].spin();
        }
    }

    void makeMove(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<nrOfComps;i++)
        {
            comps[i].move();
        }
    }

    void showAll(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<nrOfComps;i++)
        {
            comps[i].printResult();
        }
        cout<<"\n\n";

        system("pause");
    }

    int winner(Competitor comps[],int nrOfComps, int nrOfTwistPlaces)
    {
        int end = 0;
        int score = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<nrOfComps;i++)
        {
            score = comps[i].checkScore();
            if(score == nrOfTwistPlaces)
            {
                end = 1;
            }
            else end = -1;
        }
        return end;
    }
```

I'd be grateful if you would point out other mistakes if you see any.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to understand, step by step, what's going on?

Comment: What output are you expecting and what is being shown instead?

Comment: Didn't look through all the code, but one blaring mistake is you are calling `srand` multiple times in a loop. You should only call it **once** at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Didn't before,since everything was easy at first in the course.But I will look up a tutorial on how to use the debugger.I'm using CodeBlocks at the moment.Thanks for the advice. =)

Comment: Ah,where should I put srand in this case?

Comment: Just for the record, horizontal scrolling is **really annoying** when you can, please try and avoid having long lines of code like you have above.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind,thnx :)

Comment: I'm expecting the markings and direction to change with every new round,but the direction and markings remain the same all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the **Competitor** object -- add a constructor:

```
Competitor::Competitor(void)
{
    direction = 0;
    markedSpots = 0;
}
```

Also, you call **rand()**, and then do a "mod" function using the % operator -- **rand()%1+0**.  First, while we're here -- why do you add 0?

But the big issue here is that you you are doing **% 1**, which will give the remainder of dividing by 1.  Of course, this will always result in 0.

And, your main **while** statement will never exit -- you never modify **noWinner**

Comment: Should it be in the header file?I keep getting an error wherever I put it:

error: extra qualification 'Competitor::' on member 'Competitor'

Comment: Actually,I fixed that.It made a huge difference,so many thanks for that. =) It isn't working altogether yet though.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be declared same place object is declared.  Under **public:**, add **Competitor(void);**

Comment: And, so we're clear -- CALL the constructor -- modify the new:

Comment: Competitor * comps = new Competitor[nrOfComps]();

Comment: You're a lifesaver; you hit the nail on the head.It works perfectly now.Don't know how to express my gratitude,I am so relieved,since I've been working with this thing for soooo long.Thank you a million times over!